# add builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0",0) causing the packets not to be routed to destination

Tags: android, packet, packet-capture

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to capture packets in android.

When I add `builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0",0)` to my code , it's helping me capture packets, but those packets are not being routed to there destination.

Did anyone come across this problem or issues,

```
builder.addAddress("10.0.2.0", 24);
builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
builder.setSession("some service");
builder.setMtu(1500);
```

If I take the `addRoute` option out of builder, then packets are routed successfully, but when I add that I get an error and I tried `netstat` and apparently the socket status is in "SYN_WAIT"

Answer (score 2):

When you add the line `builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);` this means you are routing all packets to your application to handle them, and if you don't forward them outside the device, the application requesting it will time out and might retry again.